# How to retrieve the absolute path represented by a `Dir` object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, directory, path, filesystems, absolute-path

I want to write a method that takes a `Dir`-object as argument and does something with it, and for that I need to know the absolute path represented by this object. How do I retrieve this information?

The solution I came with is something like `File.absolute_path(dir.path)` (`dir` is the `Dir`-object in question), which doesn't work if `dir` was instantiated with a relative path and the current working directory is different from the working directory at the time of the instantiation.

Comment: Seems like Ruby's `Dir` is based on the directory stream returned by [`opendir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/opendir.html) which doesn't have the notion of an absolute path.

Comment: You are going to have to find another implementation. Maybe if you posted what you are doing we could provide alternative solutions?

Comment: @engineersmnky I am writing some utility scripts to deal with [Agda](https://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php)'s module system, which should help me with creating and refactoring modules within a project folder. I chose to use `Dir` to represent directories at first as e.g. a 'Pathname' could represent both a file and a directory, and that's when I found out about this problem. I have switched to using `Pathname` by now, but still curious about whether it is possible with `Dir`.

Comment: @XiaohuWang based on your description of the implementation `Pathname` is the correct choice as you cannot perform your desired mechanism with `Dir` unless you want to use `chdir` as well which seems like it might be awkward.

Comment: FileUtils and Pathname have capabilities to do path ascension and determine real paths. The `realpath` utility (if available on your system) can help too.